# Removing the page numbering on some pages of beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering

I am trying to remove the page numbering on the transitions pages (which are not counted thanks to the `noframenumbering`).

Currently, I have the following display on transitions: 
[image: transitionfail]

I would like to have this transition display :
[image: transitionsuccess]

(You will notice that there is no page numbering on the page)

---

**Question:** Is it possible to remove the page numbering without editing the entire theme package (I only want to remove this part, but I want to keep all the other thing)?

If no, what would be the solution in order to remove this page numbering there, but keeping all the other content on header and footer?

---

**My minimal working example:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering]
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
    \end{frame}
}

\section{section1}
\begin{frame}
We are in section1
\end{frame}

\section{section2}
\begin{frame}
We are in section2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit "dirty" solution but it works fine.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginSection[]{{                    %notice the double brackets
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
                \phantom{\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}\hspace*{2ex}        %notice the \phantom 
            \end{beamercolorbox}}
        }
        \begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering]
                \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
        \end{frame}
}}                                     %notice the double brackets
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{section1}
\begin{frame}
We are in section1
\end{frame}

\section{section2}
\begin{frame}
We are in section2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I did was to move the `\atbeginsection[]` before the start of the document and embed the infoline theme (the same used by Cambridge) without the page numbers. I included the macros responsible for the page numbering in a `\phantom{}` so to keep the same exact position of the date text.

Notice also the double brackets needed to avoid the propagation of the modified theme to all the subsequent frames.

[image]

### No numbering for a single frame

In principle you can put the modified template before any single frame and enclose everything in a group so that the template is loaded only for that frame.

```
{
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
                \phantom{\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}\hspace*{2ex}
            \end{beamercolorbox}}
        }
\makeatother
\begin{frame}
We are in section2
\end{frame}
}
```

Or you can achieve the same creating a custom frame environment that embed the modified template:

```
\newenvironment{myframe}{
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
                \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
                \phantom{\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}\hspace*{2ex}
            \end{beamercolorbox}}
        }
\makeatother
\begin{frame}}
{\end{frame}}
```

and then call your `myframe` like a custom environment

```
\begin{myframe} 
This frame will show no numbering
\end{myframe}
```

every time you want to hide the numbering. Again this is not super elegant, but works.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's a very good solution! Is this possible to make it for another (than the transition) specific frame ? Let's say that at a given frame (and this one only), I don't want to display the frame numbering as well. Can I re-exploit your given code, with, I don't know, an option to a frame?

Comment: @Gestodent yes, please see the modified answer.